# Negative Fill color in AreaSpline Graph

Tags: highcharts

I want to fill area color above the spline in area spline chart.
I have tried to set negative fill color but no result.
Can anyone let me know how to fill area color above the spline rather then below?
Any help will be appreciated.

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'areaspline'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Average fruit consumption during one week'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'left',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: 150,
                y: 100,
                floating: true,
                borderWidth: 1,
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                    'Monday',
                    'Tuesday',
                    'Wednesday',
                    'Thursday',
                    'Friday',
                    'Saturday',
                    'Sunday'
                ],
                plotBands: [{ // visualize the weekend
                    from: 4.5,
                    to: 6.5,
                    color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, .2)',
                }]
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit units'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                shared: true,
                valueSuffix: ' units'
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                areaspline: {
                    fillOpacity: 0.5
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'John',
                data: [3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 10, 12],
                negativeFillColor: '#000000'
            }, {
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4],
                negativeFillColor: '#000000'
            }]
        });
    })
```

;

Thanks,
M

Comment: Can you include the code that you've tried so far?

Comment: Hi, I have added my code to question. Please have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, threshold should work. Just you need to set

- `endOnTick: false`
- `maxPadding: 0`
- `threshold: max_value_in_data`

See: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/1076/

Code:

```
var data = [3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 10, 12];

Array.prototype.max = function() {
    return Math.max.apply(null, this);
}

$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'areaspline'
    },
    yAxis: {
        endOnTick: false,
        maxPadding: 0
    },
    plotOptions: {
        areaspline: {
            threshold: data.max(),
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: data,
        negativeFillColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)'
    }]
});
```

Comment: negativeFillColor -- brilliant! Just the solution I was looking for and didn't realize was baked in. Thank you [highcharts own example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-negative-color/)